# Azure Web Role -- how to secure an open source project?

Tags: c#, azure, encryption

I've got a web role written in a combination of C# and F#, which I would like to expose on GitHub as an open-source project.

Here is my `ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="My.Cloud.Service" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="4" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
  <Role name="My.Web.Role">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myaccount;AccountKey=<<myaccountkey>>" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.Enabled" value="true" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountUsername" value="roblyndon" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountEncryptedPassword" value="<<my encrypted password>>" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountExpiration" value="2017-05-17T23:59:59.0000000+01:00" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.Enabled" value="true" />
      <Setting name="APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" value="205ceb49-275d-4c1c-a42c-fd7e55be0229" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Certificates>
      <Certificate name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.PasswordEncryption" thumbprint="35DE0821166BCB100B2BA7FF339436DA0CBC089F" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
    </Certificates>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

I was tempted not to hide `<<my encrypted password>>` -- it is, after all, encrypted, albeit with SHA-1.

The insanity of this is that although my remote access password is encrypted, the diagnostics connection string, which points to my storage account, is directly exposed.  In fact, it contains an unencrypted version of the primary access key to my storage account.

If I put this into an open-source project, I would like to include my `cscfg` files, but obviously I can't do that while it exposes my private data so blatantly.  And putting them in `.gitignore`, as I do now, will create compilation headaches for anyone who tries to clone the repository.

Is there any way to make my `cscfg` files secure?

EDIT: Please note that this is not a generic question about hiding sensitive data in an open-source project.  There are several strategies for doing this, depending on what kind of project you are working with.  For a web role, it is very difficult to implement any of these standard solutions, and trying to do so is liable to break the build.  The obvious answer would be to `.gitignore` the entire `ccproj` cloud services project, and to give collaborators access only to the associated web project.

Comment: This is specific to Azure.  The Diagnostics connection string is generated.  The accepted answer to that question refers to a different environment in a different language; the others are too generic to be of interest.

Comment: Why don't you store those things in App Settings?

Comment: I'm confused by this question: Why do you feel you need to publish keys to your subscription, just because it's an open source project? This makes no sense.

Comment: Hi David -- this is practically "out of the box".  If you create a cloud service from the templates, and choose to include diagnostics, the setting `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString` gets published automatically, and used internally by the diagnostics infrastructure.  Similarly, if you specify that you would like to perform remote debugging, the `RemoteAccess` and `RemoteForwarder` settings get generated automatically.  The point is that I DON'T want to publish keys, and I honestly can't see where in my question you would draw the conclusion that I wanted to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is less facetious than it sounds: don't use Cloud Services.

With a web project, you can use config transforms, which are explicitly ignored, in your `.gitignore` file.  There is no such clean separation with a Web Role.

The real clue is that in the Azure Portal, Cloud Services are now appended with the damning indictment "(Classic)", which is about as close as the Microsoft product team can get to swearing.  Developers are now strongly encouraged to build app services instead, and these offer a much richer set of tools for keeping source code public whilst hiding sensitive data.  I am upgrading now, and I suspect it will save me a lot of trouble in the long term.